# Game patcher that checks for file difference between local files and new files stored on server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i'm currently working on a game in Unity, and i'm wondering how i'd approach creating a patcher for my game. I'm looking for a system similar to how Steam works, where the user has the game installed on their system, and the launcher? checks the local files of the game to the updated files on a server, and scans their checksums? to find out which files are changed, and then downloads just those files, and replaces them to the local game directory. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about version with numberings? Seems a lot less trouble to define

```
ver 1.0 = 10 files

ver 1.1 = 2 new files, 0 changes

ver 1.2 = 4 new files, 4 changes in 2 files, file 1, line 2:32, file 4, line 5:21
```

edit:

**Checksum**

```
//Getting the md5 hash
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}

//Comparing
if(thisHash == newVersionHash) 
{
    ;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: this is a valid answer why mark down... thats just rude.

Comment: The problem is I'm looking for a way to detect which files were changed between the new files and the old files. Say you have a game, that has over 200+ files and takes up about 2gb space, you could have version numbers, e.g. v1, v1.1, etc... and you could download the new files, but that would require you to download 2gb. I'm looking for a specific way to detect only the files that were changed (as some files stay the same), and only download those files to the game directory, which could cut the download required in half, if you understand what I mean

Comment: @Seabizkit Probably someone else had that answer but he beat him to it. :)

Comment: You could use a manifest. For any new or modified item, update the manifest locally. Same on server. Your manifest can be json, xml or your own, then it is just about comparing values.

Comment: @vortexdev I don't understand you.. You wouldn't have to download 2 gb? You only need to download the 'new' files and the changes for each version

Comment: @Oscar Lundber that's what I mean, but I need a way to find out which files are changed in the build, if there's a way in c# to compare those files. E.g. you have files such as game.exe, something.dll, somethingelse.dll, you check those between the server and the local files, maybe check the checksum or something to find out if the actual files have been changed, and if they have download the new file, if not don't download them

Comment: Well, use a manifest, a basic text file that is small to download and will contain everything you need to update. No need to check anything since as the dev, you know what is new. So if you change abc.dll, then add it to the manifest so the end-user can dl the manifest and see if he has the latest version of the app. If not download all content aka abc.dll.

Comment: @vortexdev Why not use git?

Comment: @CodeCaster having a versioning system is a via-able alternative to having to scan files on disk for dates. His question was simply how to i check which is newer. Answer then would simply be use the C# File IO functions to check the dates on files. If your creating a program which updates itself... it not unrealistic to create an update manifest. Becomes tricky to maintain, but if you gona build update logic the it would not be so unrealistic to keep a log of files modified since which build. It may not be the answer he was looking for but was certainly a answer non the less.

Comment: @CodeCaster OP asked for a code snippet (I think so at least, it's still a little foggy though) which i gave him. In addition to that I gave him a tip on a design idea, which he did not ask for help in implementing. If he wanted a completed system he would've hired a programmer.

Comment: @CodeCaster That analogy is not quite right, the question here is more like "How do I use a tool to cut my leg off", and I handed him a knife. And apparently OP understood what i meant and accepted the answer.

Comment: A question asker by definition is not the person who can vouch for the correctness of the answers they get, because if they knew what they were doing, they wouldn't have to ask the question. Their question _"how i'd approach creating a patcher for my game"_ has one answer: _"you don't"_. Yes, you pointed them towards an approach one could take when they're absolutely sure they want to reinvent the wheel, but again, they're mere starting points towards writing a patching system. I have explained my view, and if both you and the OP are happy, good for you.

Comment: @CodeCaster So an answer containing "you don't" and  perhaps a link to some plugin that does it for you would've gotten your upvote? 
This platform is for learning, even if the asker in your opinion _shouldn't_ pursue a project he has the right to know _"how he'd approach it"_. Which he asked, and got the answer to.

Comment: This is turning into a conversation about how answers should look on SO. This is unfortunately irrelevant to the question and blurring the help for future readers.